# Authenticate backend app on my spring rest api

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a JSF app that needs to send some data to a new webservice and I thinking about, how can I authenticate my JSF app for those requests?
The webservice is Spring and my first thought was OAuth2, but my JSF App has just a few calls [~4 CRUD + something else] to the new webAPI, It means that maybe OAuth2 is bit more complex than I need.
I do want to authorize those requests using token, but I want to have them on my webapi's database, furthermore I wouldn't like to request them by Login/Password.

Comment: You authenticate your application and do that (hopefully) from a service in your application, not from a 'jsf' application. This question is a generic one and not JSF related at all. And spring-security is for the front-end not how you authenticate to a back-end service.

Comment: yu're right! I did some changes I hope my explantion seems better now. To sum up I do want  to authenticate this back end service on my spring api, but I have just a few resources and I think oauth2 it's pretty much complex for that.